# SQL Move the data from different rows with same ID in same rows but different column

Tags: sql-server

How to move the data from different rows with same ID in same rows but different column?
For example,
I have this table

**tblEx**

```
--------------
|ID|Buy |Sell|
|--+----+----|
|1 |10  |    |
|1 |    |11  |
|2 |20  |    |
|2 |    |0   |
|3 |0   |    |
|3 |    |30  |
--------------
```

**Desired Output:**

```
--------------
|ID|Buy |Sell|
|--+----+----|
|1 |10  |11  |
|2 |20  |0   |
|3 |0   |30  |
--------------
```

Comment: Use an aggregate function (like min/max) and group by ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based from the given example and desired result, you can use `MAX()`

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Buy) AS Buy, MAX(Sell) AS Sell
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```